# Is it possible to separate regular and reverse UrlMappings in grails?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I've got a problem. For a lot existing links, I'd like to add a salted hash for security reasons. I don't want to look up and change all existing links. Really, I'd love to solve this just in UrlMappings.

Here's something that works for matching incoming requests:

```
    "/foo/$key/$hash" {
        controller = "foo"
        action = "bar"
    }
```

Here's something that works for the reverse mapping (createLink):

```
    "/foo/$key/${DigestUtils.shaHex("$salt$key")}" {
        controller = "foo"
        action = "bar"
    }
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to combine these two in one, or how to have one handle the incoming requests and the other the createLinks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a custom tag ( in a TagLib ) that will add the hash values and wrap around createLink.

So basically

createHashLink = { attrs ->

```
def hash = "${DigestUtils.shaHex("$salt$key")}"
out << createLink( mapping: 'blah', params: [ hash: hash ] ) ...
```

}

In your code, you can then just call g.createHashLink( ... ) which will work in the same way as createLink.

Comment: I know that would work, but I was hoping to do it directly from the UrlMappings. Parts of it work in UrlMappings; just putting the stuff together doesn't.